# Why initializing JSONdecoder?

Tags: swift, initialization

When looking at coding examples on how to use the JSONDecoder in Swift, most often it is first being initialised and then used. Something along those lines:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.decode(...)
```

All that usually sits within a function. What I am wondering is why doesn't the JSONDecoder be directly used? I.e. `JSONDecoder().decode(...)`. This should also work and lead to less code. Also, initialisation would anyway happen for each function call separately, so it sohuld be the same from an efficiency perspective. Am I missing something?

Comment: You might want to customise the behaviour of the decoder but otherwise your observation is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are right. However, most times developers set other properties, like the decoding strategy of the object, and *then use it*. So it makes sense to first initialize it, set the properties/option, and then decode.